# Flutter BloC flush streams on logout

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working with blocs and rxdart. There are some blocs that I don't instantiate "per-screen/widget" but globally in the app, since I need the same instance for the entire life of the app session. Therefore, I won't dispose them by closing the streams.

When I log my user out, I would like to make sure that all the streams/subjects are reset.
How can I achieve this?

Here is a simple Bloc I have:

```
class FriendsBloc {
  final FriendsRepository _friendsRepository = FriendsRepository();

  final BehaviorSubject<FriendsResponse> _friendsSubject = BehaviorSubject<FriendsResponse>();

  BehaviorSubject<FriendsResponse> get friends => _friendsSubject;

  Future<void> getFriends() async {
    try {
      FriendsResponse response = await _friendsRepository.getFriends();
      _friendsSubject.sink.add(response);
    } catch (e) {
      _friendsSubject.sink.addError(e);
    }
  }

  dispose() {
    _friendsSubject.close();
  }
}

final friendsBloc = FriendsBloc();
```

Comment: just an idea, if you're using it globally, you could instantiate your bloc upon login, and dispose it upon user logout?

Comment: The issue is that I need this bloc everywhere in my app, so I can only instantiate it the way i did on the snippet. If i close it, how do I re instantiate it ?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your question? I'm looking at a similar problem.

Comment: @kk_ sadly no i just re instantiate the streams